# Node js Bot musica

Tags: nodejs, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

Holaaaa, estoy haciendo un bot de musica con discord.js, al poner el comando en cmd de node indes.js me sale este error.
var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

El código me basé en una guía que encontre y también ya genere una KEY de la API de Google para que pueda obtener una búsqueda de contenido allí y el codígo a continuación lo enlazo desde el index.js ya que lo tengo en otra carpeta, debido a que uso un handler de eventos en Node.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports = (client) => {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    //verificamos que el usuario solicitante este conectado en un canal de voz.
      if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('¡Necesitas unirte a un canal de voz para reproducir música!');
  
      const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
  
    //verificamos que el bot tenga permisos de conectar y de hablar en el canal de voz.
      if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
        return message.channel.send('¡Necesito permisos para unirme y hablar en el canal de voz!');
      }
      var opts = {
        maxResults: 1, //Maximo de resultados a encontrar
        key: 'KEY-API-YOUTUBE', //Necesitas una CLAVE de la API de youtube. 
        type: "video" // Que tipo de resultado a obtener.
      };
    
      const songArg = await search(args.join(' '), opts);
      const songURL = songArg.results[0].link;
      const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(songURL);
    
      const song = {
        title: songInfo.title,
        url: songInfo.video_url,
        author: message.author.tag
      };
      if (!serverQueue) {
        // Si NO hay una lista de música.
        // <-- Creamos nuestra cola de música a reproducir  -->
      
      }else {
        // Si HAY una lista de música reproduciendo.
      
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        console.log(serverQueue.songs);
        return message.channel.send(`**${song.title}** ha sido añadido a la cola!, __por: ${message.author.tag}__`);
      
      }
      const queueObject = {
        textChannel: message.channel, //guardamos el canal de texto
        voiceChannel: voiceChannel, // guardamos el canal de voz
        connection: null, // un objeto para la conexión 
        songs: [], // creamos la lista de canciones
        volume: 5, // volumen al iniciar la cola
        playing: true, // un objeto para validar la cola de música en reproducción.
       };
       // <-- Establecer la cola de música  -->

// Creando el conjunto de datos para nuestra cola de música
queue.set(message.guild.id, queueObject);

// Agregamos las canciones al conjunto de datos
queueObject.songs.push(song);

// <-- Conectar al canal de voz  -->
try {
    // Aquí unimos el bot al canal de voz y guardar nuestra conexión en nuestro objeto.
    var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
    queueObject.connection = connection;
   
    message.channel.send(`Reproduciendo ahora: **${song.title}**`);
   
    // Llamar a la función de reproducción para comenzar una canción.
    play(message.guild, queueObject.songs[0]);
   
   } catch (err) {
   
    // Imprimir el mensaje de error si el bot no puede unirse al chat de voz
    console.log(err);
    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
    return message.channel.send(err);
   }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error te esta indicando exactamente cual es el problema `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`, para poder usar el await es necesario que este dentro de una función async:

```
module.exports = async (client) =>
```